# Switch Super with ALT on another keyboard only

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The keyboard on the built in Macbook Air position is 
`CTRL . ALT . SUPER`

But when I want to use it on a monitor with an external keyboard, the position of the external keyboard is
`CTRL . SUPER . ALT`

How do I override the position of the external keyboard to follow the Macbook Air position? And make sure that when i detach the keyboard, it uses back the default Macbook Air position automatically?